How create a "Relation with Role (from: users-permissions)" as in the User Content-type
I have a content type called “setting”, and I would like to configure the end-user role by entry. Instead of managing the all content type the same way, I would like something like this:

a first setting accessible for authenticated end-user

a second one for public end-user

…


First, I need to create a relation between my “setting” content type but I can’t by default
In a second time, I will need to update my controller to ensure that roles are respected.
Can someone help me with this two steps ?
I have seen nothing about that on the internet.
I have also opened a conversation on the Strapi forum.
PS: I know that it would work to create another content type (one for authenticated end-user and one for public), but it’s not what I want.
Thanks for your time.

if i get your request correct, you want some fields that are going to fetched only if user has an ownership, well you can do that using middleware, there you go a straight implementation:
Private strapi data for current user
